# How to connect to remote System via ssh with Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, ssh, visual-studio-2022

I would like to attach to a Process with the visual studio debugger, which is accessible via SSH. Actually, there is a Linux container running in Kubernetes and I got the access with `port-forward`. This allows me to access the container directly via SSH with `putty` and I would also like to connect Visual Studio via SSH:

[image]

Unfortunately, I don't get an error message when I try to access the container with a private key. The access logs from Visual Studio only say:

```
[Info, Thread 1]    liblinux.RemoteSystemBase: Disconnecting over SSH from "127.0.0.1:22"
```

I recorded the connection attempt once, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

[Video](https://screenrec.com/share/6x1qT8E9em)

Thanks

Comment: Hi Mate, 
I was wondering if you managed to find the issue, Im trying to use sam setup for debugging using vs2022 and any help would be highly appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open PuTTYgen
2. Load your .ppk private key
3. Select Conversions/Export OpenSSH key
4. Save with .key extension
5. In VS2022 connection dialog choose than .key private key file